# Calculating distance between matching intersections using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, layers, distance, intersection

I have a streetmap with the coordinates of some speed limit signs (which mark either the beginning or the ending of a speed limit and hold the applicable speed limit in km/h). With regard to the direction of driving, the signs are always positioned on the right side of the road:
[image]

What I want to do now is to create a new line layer which shows the speed sections (the length in km of the speed section and the speed limit in km/h itself).

As you can see the red rectangle in the image above, I will cover the marked area in an example:
[image]

In order to do that, I guess I will have to create normal vectors with the points of the speed signs and the streets itself in order to get intersections directly on the streetline. I know how to do that by now. But how can I "drive" along the streetline to sequentially check each speed sign in order to extract the speed sections? Let's take the picture above as an example: If I start south at the beginning of the 70 km/h speedsection, I have to drive north (because it is the driving direction of the street) and check each speed sign along the line for the end of the speed section. After that, I search for the next beginning speed section and so on.

How can that be realized?
Please comment if you need more details on that issue.

Answer (score 3):

This is just about how to check the speed value from the speed sign nearby the start point of each section.

- Please assume your road section is a polyline from **node 0** to **node n**. Here n=4 on the below, red arrow example (driving northeast then north).
- And a point layer `speed_signs` has `speed` field.
- The driving azimuth at the start point (node 0) "**A**" is given by `angle_at_vertex( $geometry, vertex:=0 )` this is a clockwise angle starting from north.
- From the start point, the speed post (**40 km/h**) should be on the right hand side, its direction (from the start point) "**B**" is `azimuth(start_point($geometry), geomnearest(‘speed_signs’, ‘$geometry’))`
   (please note `geomnearest()` function is from **refFunction** plugin). Probably `degrees()` is required to convert the radians to degrees.
- To avoid another nearby speed sign (on the opposite side; **30 km/h**), the angle between the road and the speed post (`B - A`) has to be less than 180 degrees. Conditional statement something like `CASE WHEN (B - A) < 180 THEN...` would be useful.
- Then the speed data can be taken, again by using **refFunction** `geomnearest('speed_signs', 'speed')`.

[image]

Comment: I do not quite understand how the speed post (40km/h for instance) can have a direction? Same here with the nodes. what if a node is located directly on a crossroad? What will my direction then be? I am trying to calculate the speed sections of a whole streetnet - with speed posts located all around. In which way can I realize this then?

Comment: @applebrown Please edit your question and add scenarios you want to be covered by potential answers. I think I have answered for the case you have described in your original post.

Comment: edited my question and it is more detailed now! :)